# for loop returning unexpected values when squaring values

Tags: python

I have two lists that I want to square
the following code is working

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
a_sqrd = []
b_sqrd = []
for i in a:
    a_sqrd.append(a[i]*a[i])
    b_sqrd.append(b[i]*b[i])

print a_sqrd
print b_sqrd
```

result:

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

[1, 9, 16, 25, 25, 9, 4, 1, 16, 64, 81]

but when I try

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
a_sqrd = []
b_sqrd = []
for i in a:
    a_sqrd.append(a[i]*a[i])
for i in b:
    b_sqrd.append(b[i]*b[i])

print a_sqrd
print b_sqrd
```

result:

[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

[9, 25, 1, 9, 9, 25, 16, 9, 25, 16, 64]

why does running two for loops affect list b?
Im expecting the same result as in a, im sure there is something obvious im missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You iterate over the list by using `for elem in testList`, which yields elements of the list and not their indices.

```
>>> b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
>>> for i in b:
        print i,


1 3 -4 5 5 3 2 1 4 8 9 # Whereas you expected 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

So, your code fetches the elements using the values as the indices and returns the square of those values. This is what happens -

```
>>> for index, val in enumerate(b): # enumerate yields an (index, value) tuple which gets unpacked.
        print '{0} : {1}*{1} = {2}'.format(index, val, val**2)


0 : 1*1 = 1
1 : 3*3 = 9
2 : -4*-4 = 16
3 : 5*5 = 25
4 : 5*5 = 25
5 : 3*3 = 9
6 : 2*2 = 4
7 : 1*1 = 1
8 : 4*4 = 16
9 : 8*8 = 64
10 : 9*9 = 81
```

Whereas in your initial code, **the `a` list happens to be the indices you're expecting** which builds up the correct list as you observed.

**Easier Solutions** -

You could use a list comprehension to build up your lists, like (No Need to multiply a number by itself if you're looking for it's square, just use the builtin exponentiation operator (`**`))

```
>>> [elem**2 for elem in a]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>> [elem**2 for elem in b]
[1, 9, 16, 25, 25, 9, 4, 1, 16, 64, 81]
```

Or a solution using `map`.

```
>>> map(lambda x: x**2, a)
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>> map(lambda x: x**2, b)
[1, 9, 16, 25, 25, 9, 4, 1, 16, 64, 81]
```

Comment: @Downvoter : Could you please leave a comment? I would really like to improve upon my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension more easily:

```
>>> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a_sqrd=[e*e for e in a]
>>> a_sqrd
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>> b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
>>> b_sqrd=[e*e for e in b]
>>> b_sqrd
[1, 9, 16, 25, 25, 9, 4, 1, 16, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't doing what you think it is:

```
for i in a:
    ...
```

as the `i` values are the actual values in the array.

You aren't noticing because the array values are `0,1,2,3,4,5...` in the first array.

So in your code you need to change it to this:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
a_sqrd = []
for i in a:
    a_sqrd.append(i**2)

print a_sqrd
```

or to do bother of them;

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [1, 3, -4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 9]
a_sqrd = []
b_sqrd = []
for i, j in zip(a, b):
    a_sqrd.append(i**2)
    b_sqrd.append(j**2)

print a_sqrd
print b_sqrd
```